# Can asp.net Razor Pages maintain programmable threads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm coming from building Web-Interfaces from scratch (without any Framework, just HTML/PHP/CSS/JS) and I now try to "evolve". I really like using C# for all my recent projects which is why I found out about ASP.NET and Razor Pages.

I'm not sure if I understand them correctly, can I see Razor Pages ASP.NET Web-Applications as an "Application" we're used to? Which means, can I implement parallel working processing code while the user browses the site?

As an example, i plan to create a web-interface which shows continuous input data from sensors via Networking. Would this be possible, e.g. with a Thread receiving and processing data and then showing on the Website?

If not, what would the preferred framework or solution be?

I find all the tutorials to be to complex to find an answer to this question quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that can be done but using some technologies.To do so you can use SignalR to Notify the clients with the updated changes

Signalr:is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications. Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather than having the server wait for a client to request new data.

https://www.asp.net/signalr

Then You can use WebAPIs for SPA or Just rest calls so as use can use the system normally and the server responds to your method execution async.

https://www.asp.net/web-api